# Determining Measurability given property of symmetric difference

Tags: measure-theory

I came across this statement and I am not sure why it is true.

If $\mu$ is sub-additive and $\mu(E\bigtriangleup F)$ is in the null set (where $E \bigtriangleup F$ denotes the symmetric difference of $E$ and $F$), and $F$ is $\mu$-measurable, then $ E$ is necessarily $\mu$-measurable as well.

Any ideas on how the proof would go would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the hypothesis that the measure space is complete. A measure space is complete if its associated sigma-algebra contains all subsets of sets of measure zero. With this additional hypothesis, the proof of the result runs as follows

We have

$$0 = \mu(E \triangle F) = \mu\left(E\setminus F\: \bigcup F\: \setminus E\right) = \mu(E \setminus F) + \mu(F \setminus E)$$

where the measurability $E\setminus F$ and $F \setminus E$ follows from the completeness assumption.

hence $\mu(E\setminus F) = 0$ and $\mu(F \setminus E) = 0$.

We have $$F = \left(F\setminus E\right) \bigcup \left(E\bigcap F\right)$$ where the union is disjoint. Thus
$$E\bigcap F = F \setminus \left(F \setminus E\right)$$

It then follows that $E \bigcap F$ is measurable, since $F$ and $F \setminus E$ are both measurable.

Now
$$E = \left(E\setminus F\right) \bigcup \left(E \bigcap F\right)$$

We have shown that $E\setminus F$ and $E \bigcap F$ are measurable. It then follows that $E$ is measurable.